# make swf from fla without ever opening it

Tags: linux, actionscript-3, command-line, flash

is it possible to change text and images in a fla file without ever opening it up and then making the swf via command line? I want to make a flash template and save the fla. Then be able to update my text and image name and convert it to swf. I have one template but tons of different text options and background images. It would be nice to be able to copy the master.fla twenty times and just change the source code (will do this from command line) and then convert to swf (via command line).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not what you're after; however, would be a good use of the Flex mxmlc command line compiler.  Maybe even Flash Builder could automate this as pure ActionScript.  Why don't you load XML for your template?  Or statically embed the XML if you want content statically linked to your byte code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CS5, you can do half of what you're asking today, by using the XFL file format instead of FLA. Instead of a binary blob, you get an editable XML file and a tree of separate asset files: PNGs, AS3 files, etc. You can then modify the XML or AS3 files programmatically to get your variants.

(A CS5 FLA file is really just a zipped up version of the XFL, but there's no advantage to using that instead of an XFL. In CS4 and previous, FLA was a proprietary binary format.)

The missing piece is an XFL compiler. Adobe currently provides no such thing, and the third party market hasn't yet produced one.

You could use a systems automation tool to drive the Flash Professional environment through the compilation steps. On OS X, for example, either Automator or AppleScript should be able to do what you want. It'll just have more overhead than the command line compiler you were hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jason, there are a lot of alternatives to what you suggest. Keeping content out of the SWF is good practice actually. This is a good way to avoid large files!

Depending on what you 're looking to achieve, there are a lot of solutions available. XML is an option, JSON another.

If you're looking to build a template, any of the above would seem appropriate.

It sounds like you're working from the Flash IDE, as Jason suggests you may want to have a look at another IDE, such as FlashDevelop, FDT or FlashBuilder as they make coding with AS3 a lot easier.